# WCF Service Sharing Types

Tags: vb.net, wcf

I am writing a WCF service and code to consume it and I want to share data types between these services.

I have a WCF library with the types I want to share defined in it. My WCF service and my WCF client both reference the assembly from the library. Classes look like this:

```
<DataContract()> _
Public Class MyEntity

    Private _culture As String = String.Empty
    Private _name As String = String.Empty    

    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property ID As Integer
        Get
            Return _id
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As Integer)
            _id = Value
        End Set
    End Property


    <DataMember()> _
    Public Property Name() As String
        Get
            Return _name
        End Get
        Set(ByVal Value As String)
            _name = Value
        End Set
    End Property

End Class
```

What I would like to do in my consuming application is create an instance of MyEntity and assign it's value to the return value of a method in my service that, naturally , returns an instance of MyEntity.

So when I add a reference to my service from my client and give the service namespace the name "MyWCF" I would like to something like:

```
Dim entity as new MyEntity
dim srv as new MyWCF.MyServiceClient
entity = srv.MyMethod()
```

Right now when I do this the compiler gives me an error because it cannot implicitly convert type  myclientnamespace.MySCF.Myclass to myclientnamespace.MyClass. I have read the posts [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2037182/problem-with-wcf-and-multiple-namespaces-sharing-object-types-across-multiple) and the article [here](http://blog.walteralmeida.com/2010/08/wcf-tips-and-tricks-share-types-between-server-and-client.html) - which was referenced in another stackoverflow thread. These state that if my client code is referencing the same assembly as my service code and I have that assembly reference in **before**
I create the service reference the client code should **not** create proxy classes and rather use the classes in the referenced entity assembly. I have tried this and it is not working. I even made sure that the "Reuse types in all referenced assemblies" radio button is checked when I create the service reference.

My questions are :

**Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here? Should creating the service reference after the entities assembly reference was made not result in reusing the types?**

**Is it possible to reuse types in this fashion?**

Any advice would be very much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely possible to reuse your types in this fashion.  If you create your client proxy by hand you'll have more control over this behavior, including the namespacing.  The proxy doesn't need to do anything with your shared data types, they can be excluded from the proxy and thus exist in only one namespace in the shared assembly.